# Magento:2.3.2: Add to cart is not working after element moved

Tags: layout, addtocart, magento2.3.2

I tried to move an element to above add-to-cart block at category page.

**Please check the following attachments.**

[image]

**I need as the following:**

[image]

For product availability, I am using an extension. The name of that plugin for the element is `mageArray.checkDelivery`.

I used the following at my layout default.xml file as follows:

```
<move element="product.info.addtocart" destination="product.info.main" after="mageArray.checkDelivery"/>
```

**I tried the above code to change the position of the product availability block. **

Then I get the layout of add to cart and pin availability as per my requirement.

**But, from now, add to cart is not working**.

My website : https://www.depoto.com/taparia-mh200-machinist-hammers-with-handle.html

Comment: Have you check console or error log?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your AddtoCart Button out of  the form id="product_addtocart_form"

[image]

please move your addtocart Button with form like:

[image]

xml move

```
<move element="product.info" destination="product.info.main" after="mageArray.checkDelivery"/>
```

Hope this will help you. thanks

Comment: Yes, i just seen that its out of form. Can you tell me how to do it it form?

Comment: thanks its working. <move> above code

Comment: @RanjeetKumar, please add the move code in answer. then i can accept

Comment: @TejaBhagavanKollepara my answer updated. thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have to check your website and I have to find it what is an exact issue on your site.
In your addtocart action form action not available

Your AddtoCart HTML:-

```
<div class="box-tocart">
        <div class="fieldset">
                <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span>Qty:</span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" data-validate="{&quot;required-number&quot;:true,&quot;validate-item-quantity&quot;:{&quot;minAllowed&quot;:1,&quot;maxAllowed&quot;:10000}}">
                <div class="qty-changer">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty-inc"><i class="porto-icon-up-dir"></i></a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty-dec"><i class="porto-icon-down-dir"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action primary tocart" id="product-addtocart-button">
                <span>Add to Cart</span>
            </button>
</div>
```

My AddtoCart HTML:-

```
<div class="product-add-form">
    <form data-product-sku="sdfggdsfsdfsd" action="http://localhost/c/index.php/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovLzE5Mi4xNjguMC4xMC9jL2luZGV4LnBocC9zZGZnZ2RzZi5odG1s/product/75/" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input type="hidden" name="product" value="75">
        <input type="hidden" name="selected_configurable_option" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="">
        <input type="hidden" name="item" value="75">
        <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="lGxI5yhFm66Nw1rc">                            
        <div class="box-tocart">
            <div class="fieldset">
                <div class="field qty">
                    <label class="label" for="qty"><span>Qty:</span></label>
                    <div class="control">
                        <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty" data-validate="{&quot;required-number&quot;:true,&quot;validate-item-quantity&quot;:{&quot;minAllowed&quot;:1,&quot;maxAllowed&quot;:10000}}">
                        <div class="qty-changer">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty-inc"><i class="porto-icon-up-dir"></i></a>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="qty-dec"><i class="porto-icon-down-dir"></i></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <button type="submit" title="Add to Cart" class="action primary tocart" id="product-addtocart-button">
                        <span>Add to Cart</span>
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</form>
</div>
```

Check below xml to move addtocart element

```
<move element="product.info" destination="product.info.main" after="mageArray.checkDelivery"/>
```

Hope this will help you..!

Comment: check it I have updated my answer